# How can I set Selenium to read texts in UTF-8?

Tags: selenium, perl, utf-8

I want to test a webiste which is not in english, and has some characters like `äüöé`. I'm getting an element with the following code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Chrome;
use Selenium::Waiter qw/wait_until/;
use Encode::Detect::Detector;

my $chrome_driver_path = "chromedriver.exe";
my $driver;
my %settings = (
    'binary' => $chrome_driver_path,
);

$driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(%settings);
$driver->get("website_with_utf");
my $element_id = 'my_element';
my $element;
$element = $driver->find_elements("//label[\@id='$element_id']"))[0];

if (defined($element)){
    print ("element_id: '$element_id' found");
}else{
    print ("element_id: '$element_id' could not be found");
    return -1;
}
my $text = $element->get_text();
my $encoding_text = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($option_text);
print "SELENIUM before enconding for *$option_text*: $encoding_text\n";         

$text = encode('UTF-8', $text, Encode::FB_CROAK) if (defined($text));

$encoding_text = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($option_text);
print "SELENIUM after enconding for *$option_text*: $encoding_text\n";
```

This returns:

> SELENIUM before enconding for *öaö*:
>
> SELENIUM after enconding for *öaö*: EUC-KR

I would like to have get_text returning an UTF-8 value and not have to write everysingle time that encode line and import the econde library. I have tried many combinations of use utf8 and `use utf8::all;` but I had no success. Is there a cleaner way to solve this issue?

Comment: If you want the module to return something different, you'll have to tell it to do so (if it provides a way to let you). But you didn't even mention what module you're using. Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem, as required. See [mcve].

Comment: Otherwise, there are these marvelous things called subs which help us avoid repeating a sequence of statements...

Comment: `use utf8;` tells Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8. Not useful here.

Comment: `use utf8:all;` doesn't affect modules, at least not directly.

Comment: @ikegami I added the common statements for all selenium scripts. I'm asking if it is possible somehow set utf8 as default output in the selenium framework.

Comment: Good enough. I've used Selenium::Chrome before. Going to bed; I'll look at it what I get up

Comment: 8 hours not enough? :P

Answer (score 1):

The module currently returns decoded text as it should. (See demonstration below.)

It doesn't make sense for it to return encoded text, UTF-8 or otherwise. Inputs should be decoded.

It's outputs that should be encoded. If the encoded text is going to STDOUT or a file, you can have this done automatically by adding an encoding layer to the handle, perhaps using

```perl
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

---

```perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

use Selenium::Chrome qw( );

sub on_destroy(&) {
   my ($cb) = @_;
   return bless(\$cb, "My::On::Destroy");
}

sub My::On::Destroy::DESTROY {
   my ($self) = @_;
   $$self->();
}

{
   my $web_driver;

   my $guard = on_destroy {
      if ($web_driver) {
         $web_driver->shutdown_binary();
         $web_driver = undef;
      }
   };

   $web_driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(
      binary => "$RealBin/chromedriver.exe",
   );

   for (
      [ "UTF-8",        "utf8"   ],
      [ "Windows-1252", "cp1252" ],
   ) {
      my ($enc, $code) = @$_;  # $code is assumed to be safe for url path segments.
      say "$enc:";
      $web_driver->get("http://www.adaelis.com/misc/encoding/$code.html");
      for my $element ($web_driver->find_elements("/html/body/p")) {
         say sprintf "%vX", $element->get_text();
      }
   }
}
```

Output (annotated):

```
UTF-8:
E9              # HTML: «é» encoded using UTF-8.  Returned: Code Point for «é».
2660            # HTML: «♠» encoded using UTF-8.  Returned: Code Point for «♠».
2660            # HTML: «&#x2660;».               Returned: Code Point for «♠».
Windows-1252:
E9              # HTML: «é» encoded using cp1252. Returned: Code Point for «é».
2660            # HTML: «&#x2660;».               Returned: Code Point for «♠».
```